# PostgreSQL: optimise table access within a loop

Tags: postgresql, loops, plpgsql

Operating system: OSX El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G1004)
PostgreSQL 9.5.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76), 64-bit

I am running a local instance of a PostgreSQL database. I have a main table `t` that I want to join with several tables `t_i` and append the results in one output table `t_out`. I created a `PL/PGSQL` function (see example below) with a loop that iterates through a table, fetches the name of tables `t_i` and for each table runs the SQL statement for the join. Because `t` is a quite big table and the joining operation very long, I am interested in trying to optimise the function.

I would like to know whether, within the loop, the main table is read only once and used for all the iterations or it is read each time. If the second case is true, is there a way to optimise the function, so that the main table is read only once?

I am adding an example, for clarity:

```
 ---- CREATE SAMPLE TABLES
-- Main table
CREATE TABLE test_main (gid integer, descr text, PRIMARY KEY (gid));
INSERT INTO test_main VALUES (1,'a');
INSERT INTO test_main VALUES (2,'c');
INSERT INTO test_main VALUES (3,'b');
-- Two joining tables
CREATE TABLE test_1 (gid integer, var2 text, PRIMARY KEY (gid));
INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES (1,'xx');
INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES (2,'zx');
INSERT INTO test_1 VALUES (3,'yx');
CREATE TABLE test_2 (gid integer, var2 text, PRIMARY KEY (gid));
INSERT INTO test_2 VALUES (1,'zz');
INSERT INTO test_2 VALUES (2,'yy');
INSERT INTO test_2 VALUES (3,'yz');
-- List of joining tables 
CREATE TABLE iteration (iter text, PRIMARY KEY (iter));
INSERT INTO iteration VALUES ('test_1');
INSERT INTO iteration VALUES ('test_2');

---- Join function
CREATE FUNCTION test_pg() 
  RETURNS TABLE (gid integer, descr text, var2 text) 
  AS $$
    DECLARE 
      i text;
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN SELECT iter FROM iteration 
      LOOP
        RETURN QUERY
          EXECUTE format('SELECT t1.gid, descr, var2 
                         FROM test_main t1 
                         JOIN %s t2 
                         ON t1.gid = t2.gid', i);
        END LOOP;
    RETURN;
    END;
    $$ 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql 
  STABLE;

SELECT * FROM test_pg();
```

To complete the information, the real case is a geometrical intersection in PostGIS between the geometry of buildings and several offsets of the geometry of roads.

Comment: Might be more efficient to join once to a union: `select .. from test_main t1 join (select gid, .. from t_1 union all select ... from t_1 union all ..) on ...`

Comment: The design however seems a bit strange. Why can't you merge all those `test_XX` tables into a single one?

Comment: I will try both solutions. Thank you.